# Aguasome functors of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative rings, $A-\mathbf{Mod}_f$ be the category of finite type $A$-modules. A functor $F:A-\mathbf{Mod}_f\rightarrow B-\mathbf{Mod}_f$ is said to be *aguasome* if is additive and there is a functorial isomorphism $F(Hom_A(M,N))\simeq Hom_{B}(F(M),F(N))$. Is there a classification of such functors? (à la EILENBERG-WATTS), in particular is every such functor the extension of scalars with respect to a flat morphism?

Comment: Don't you mean [fully faithful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_and_faithful_functors#Formal_definitions)?

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon nope I mean aguasome! $Hom_A(M,N)$ is itself an $A$-module, this is essential here.

Comment: What if $F$ sends every $A$-module to $B$?

Comment: Ah, I had missed the "commutative-algebra" tag...

Comment: @Jay good point, you remind me that we need some more conditions to get a characterization

Comment: @Jay: that doesn't specify what $F$ does on morphisms. In general no such functor will exist, at least not an additive one. It suffices to find some $A, B$ and some finite type $A$-module $M$ such that there is no ring homomorphism $\text{End}_A(M) \to \text{End}_B(B) \cong B^{op}$; for example they might be fields of different characteristics.

Comment: The OP should specify here that $A$ and $B$ are commutative.

Comment: I agree with Mr. Yuan. In particular the OP should assume $F$ to be additive from the start; I think that $A$ and $B$ are commutative is understood (commutative algebra tag).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I know it's not additive, but it's practically implied that my functor before sends morphisms to the identity morphism of $B$. At first I was going to send every $A$-module to $0$ instead (which is additive but not interesting). You make a good point about $\operatorname{End}$ though. Now I'm wondering: what can be said in general about additive functors from $A$-modules to $B$-modules that commute with $\operatorname{End}$?

Comment: For what it's worth, I also think that aguasome functors should be required to be additive

Comment: I added the additivity condition. It was understood, tho (for functors between additive categories you usually consider only additive ones).$

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question, there are examples that are not extension of scalars with respect to a flat morphism.

For example, let $\varphi:B\to A$ be a ring epimorphism, and $F$ the obvious functor given by restriction along $\varphi$.

Or you can compose one of the examples you've thought of with one of mine. For example, the functor that takes a $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space $V$ to the $\mathbb{Z}[t]$-module $V\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}[t]$.